# Form,undefined index PHP

Tags: php, html

I have this form in HTML.

```
<form action="InsertUser.php" method="POST" enctype="text/plain" name="usuario">
<p>Nombre:<input type="text" name="nombre"><br>
<p><input type="submit">
<input type="reset" name="Submit2" value="Borrar">
```

PHP file is:

```
<?php 
  echo $_POST["nombre"];
?>
```

When I complete my form and I send my form, result is:

> "Notice: Undefined index: nombre in C:\xampp\htdocs\Curso\Practica\InsertUser.php on line 10"

Comment: remove your enctype attribute and try again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`form` only supports two enctypes `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` and `multipart/form-data`, the first is default, the second is needed when you have like file inputs. Remove the `enctype` attribute you have set and the form should submit the values correctly.

[W3C Form Specs](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#adef-enctype)

Answer (score 1):

```
<form action="InsertUser.php" method="POST" name="usuario">
<p>Nombre:<input type="text" name="nombre">
<br>
<p><input type="submit" value="Send">
<input type="reset" name="Submit2" value="Borrar">
```

edit: being "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" enctype's default is not necessary to add any for a regular form. The case being a form holding a file of any type to be uploaded it should be enctype="multipart/form-data".

Comment: An explanation could be quite helpful here as well ... why do you think it's a solution? What was the error?

Comment: Edited with a short explanation.